# ResourceBundleMessagesource - No way to access all properties from a file?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, resourcebundle

Came across this issue, while implementing i18n using spring resource bundle, for a spring based java project, which has a html+js UI.

I need to read all content from a properties file, for a particular locale, and pass this info to the client side, so that the relevant messages can be shown on the UI.

However, the ResourceBundleMessagesource/ReloadableResourceBundleMessagesource objects seem to allow retrieving only a single message at a time.

```
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource msgSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
//Methods to get only a single message at a time
String message = msgSource.getMessage("edit.delete.success", null, new Locale(localeString));
```

I am currently using java.util.ResourceBundle, and looping over the object using it's keyset.

```
rB = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", new Locale(localeString));
Map<String, String> msgs = new HashMap<>();

for(String messageKey : rB.keySet()){
msgs.put(messageKey, rB.getString(messageKey));
}
```

Q1 : Is there any better/more elegant way to solve this?

Q2 : What is the reason for the authors to not allow for accessing all properties from a file ?

Comment: They aren't properties they are messages. The task of the `MessageSource` is to convert a message code into a message. Its task isn't to provide access to properties. If you want that then do that, load it as a `java.util.Properties` object and return that to the client. Don't use `MessageSource` in this case.

Comment: Why does MessageSource not provide access to all messages, for a particular locale?
Is there a way to get all the messages in a particular file using MessageSource, or any related helper classes? I am using java.util.ResourceBundle right now, to get all the messages, I am looking for a better way.

Comment: Because that isn't its function, the function is to get the message based on the locale and code. Not to get all the messages.